# Menu hover state lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I like my menu to be interaction on `:hover`.

So here is the code:

```
$('#menu img').hover(function (){
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('menuon');
    return false;
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('menuoff');
    return false;
});
```

This code works fine, but the side effect is when the *menuon* state is over, it looses it class and become off.

On do you handle that.... I like the on state to stay on!

Here is [the working page](http://produits-lemieux.com/index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by removing the current menu item from the hover events:

```
$('#menu img:not(.menuon)').hover(
...
```

BUT you are mixing the current menu item style with the hover style, and I think that this is confusing to the user.

It will probable look better if you only apply the hover styles with javascript and add a currentMenu class to style the current menu entry slightly different from the menuon style.

```
<img src="layout/menu_acceuil.jpg" class="currentMenu" /> 
<img src="layout/menu_pourquoi.jpg" /> 
...
```

Comment: nice solution i will think of ! :-)

Comment: great help, work nice, thanks ! I have learn something today !

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the dom, you'll see that both menuoff and menuon are being added. Instead you should explicity remove the classes instead:

```
$('#menu img').hover(function (){
    $(this).removeClass('menuoff');
    $(this).addClass('menuon');
    return false;
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('menuon');
    $(this).addClass('menuoff');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Like meder said, you need to specify the class to remove.  I wouldn't have an alternate class for an off state.  All you need is:

```
$('#menu img').hover(function (){
    $(this).addClass('menuon');
    return false;
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('menuon');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it work without specifying the class name? The jQuery documentation has an example:     $("p:eq(1)").removeClass();

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass